# Anime/cartoon about a boy and a stone dog

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

Anime/cartoon about a boy and a stone dog. The dog was a stone statue who spoke without opening his mouth. There was some kind of magician or just man in a hat in the anime, if I'm not mistaken. The strangest thing is that I clearly remember that the anime was called "Stone Dog", but there is no information on the Internet. I hope this isn't my hallucination.

I'm sorry for my English..

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Your English is fine, BTW, I wouldn't have guessed it's not your first language.  When did you see this?  Where?  (What country, and what medium?)  Did the dog move at all?

Comment: There's a dog named "Chalk" in *Dr. Stone* -- but it's flesh and alive, and AFAIK doesn't talk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might it be *[Gargoyle of Yoshinaga House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargoyle_of_Yoshinaga_House)*?

[image: Front cover of Gargoyle of Yoshinaga House]

> *Gargoyle of Yoshinaga House* (吉永さん家のガーゴイル, Yoshinaga-san Chi no Gargoyle) is a Japanese light novel series written by Sennendou Taguchi, following Kazumi Yoshinaga and his normal junior high school life with younger sister Futaba Yoshinaga, who, in a lottery, won a prize of a wolf-like gargoyle nicknamed "Gar-kun".

It appears that, in the anime, indeed the "dog" speaks without moving its mouth.

The man in the hat might be [Kaitou Hyakushiki](https://www.animecharactersdatabase.com/characters.php?id=10484), a thief in the series.

[image: Images of Kaitou Hyakushiki]

Found by searching for `anime boy "dog statue"`, which led me to [this Reddit query](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/pxzur5/anime_with_a_dog_statue/).

Comment: OH MY GOD, THIS IS WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR!! Thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help. It looks like a cute series.